# Apache ProxyPass local NAT devices

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

Attempting to use ProxyPass for some web-ui's to devices on the local NAT, the config below isn't quite working.

chrome console log;

```
/ddwrt/common.js:-1 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
/ddwrt/style/elegant/style.css:-1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html.
/ddwrt/lang_pack/english.js:-1 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
/ddwrt/images/paypal.gif:-1 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html.
/ddwrt/images/88_en_interpayments.png:-1 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME
/ddwrt/:563 Uncaught ReferenceError: share is not defined
/ddwrt/:566 Uncaught ReferenceError: share is not defined
/ddwrt/:570 Uncaught ReferenceError: share is not defined
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)
english.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site;

```
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all

            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None

            AddDefaultCharset off

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Password Required"
            AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwords
            Require valid-user
    </Proxy>

    #RewriteEngine On

    <Location /ddwrt/>
            ProxyPass http://192.168.1.3
            ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.3
            RequestHeader unset referer

            #SetOutputFilter proxy-html

            ProxyHTMLURLMap http://192.168.1.3/ /
            #ProxyHTMLURLMap / /ddwrt/
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting out the ProxyHTMLUrlMap statement?

It is only needed if the proxied HTML code contains absolute links (http://host.name/foo). Relative links (/foo) should work just fine without it.

Comment: yep - no difference :( (Have tried multiple combinations of commenting out the ProxyHTMLURLMap/SetOutputFilter/RequestHeader)